# Array value passed to directive is undefined in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with multiple attributes. One of the attributes is used to bind array value to the directive. I `console.log(scope)` in `link` function and see its property attached but it is undefined. It has property `countObj:undefined`

The array basically contains : `countArray= [0,1..]`

I want to pass the values 0 to directive1 and 1 to directive2 etc.. The values in array increase to next number(2 if last value is 1) if a new directive is created. I am using `ng-repeat` to display the directives and increment array(0,1,2..) when I want a new directive. I want to pass respective array value to each directive.

First, I have $scope.countArray = [0] by default so `ng-repeat` has one value and one directive is displayed by default. So at least the first directive's `console.log(scope.countObj)` is supposed to contain a value and not `undefined`.

This is the html that uses the directive:

```
 <month-dir  ng-repeat="count in countArray" countObj="countArray[count]" on-cl="removeDirCtrl(removeVal)" obj="ebObj.costArray[count]">
            <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</month-dir>
```

The attribute `countObj` above is supposed to contain the values but is undefined when I `console.log(scope.countObj)`

This is the directive:

```
    ebApp.directive('monthDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'htmlFiles/monthDirective.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            ebObj: "=obj",
            onCl: "&",
            countObj: "=" //this is undefined
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.change = function (changedUnit) {
                changedUnit.totalCost = 0;
                //console.log(changedUnit);
                changedUnit.totalCost = changedUnit.unitsConsumed * 50;
                console.log(scope);
                console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.model));
            }
            scope.removeDir = function (removeVal) { 
                console.log(removeVal); 
                scope.onCl({ removeVal: attrs.model }); 
            }

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            //console.log($scope);
        }
    }
})
```

In controller I have this `$scope.countArray = [0];` so that there is at least one directive when page loads. When I want new directives I do this :

```
$scope.addDirective = function () {
    $scope.countArray.push($scope.countArray.length);

}
```

The new value is supposed to be passed to directive's scope in `ng-repeat`. But it won't work. I get undefined

Comment: try to get using `scope.$parent`

Comment: I think you need to use `count-obj` as the attr in your html, not `countObj`. You don't need to use the array index `count-obj="countArray[count]"`, you can just use `count-obj="count"`.

Comment: @DanielWarke. you're right. thanks. write as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `count-obj` as the attr in your html, not `countObj`. You don't need to use the array index `count-obj="countArray[count]"`, you can just use `count-obj="count"`.